# Передача id объекта View в метод контроллера ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Есть БД с перечнем кандидатов, с помощью EF создал DbContext -

**VoterContext VC = new VoterContext();**

из которого вытягиваю данные в представление

```
public ActionResult Candidats()
    {
        IEnumerable<Candidat> candidats = VC.candidats;
        ViewBag.Candidat = candidats;
        return View();
    }
```

В представлении данные из БД транслируются с помощь цикла @foreach

```
@foreach (var b in ViewBag.Candidat)
    {
        <tr>                
            <td><p>@b.CandidatInfo</p></td>
            <td><p>@b.CandidatPartion</p></td>
            <td><p>@b.CandidatProgramm</p></td>
            <td><p><a href="/Home/Vote/@b.CandidatId">Проголосовать</a></p></td>
        </tr>
    }
```

В цикле есть переход к методу

```
<a href="/Home/Vote/@b.CandidatId">Проголосовать</a>
```

Вопрос: Как создать метод в контроллере, который при нажатии на кнопку транслировал бы только те данные из выборки @foreach, которую выбрал пользователь? То есть - в синтаксис Razor вместо @b. поместить CandidatId указанного кандидата?

Прошу прощения за не точности в вопросе, из за этой "чудо-технологии" сплошная каша в голове.

Comment: Хранить список моделей во `ViewBag` совсем не по MVC канонам...

Comment: после того как Razor отработает, на клиенте будет html разметка где вместо переменных будут значения, т.е. `@b.CandidatId` будет содержать `Id` объекта. Вы хотите предоставить возможность пользователю выбрать несколько элементов списка и проголосовать за них?!

Answer (score 2):

> Есть метод в контроллере, который выводит перечень данных в компонент View с помощью @foreach цикла.

Нет, это не метод и не в контроллере, это кусок кода из вьюхи.

```
ActionResult Vote(string id)
{
    достать данные из бд по id
    return View(данные)
}
```

Вообще, как-то размыто написано, уточните ваш вопрос.

Comment: Привел больше данных, думаю так будет более понятен вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Я бы вам советовал по Модели организовать View (строго типизированно)

```
@foreach (var b in Model)
{
    <tr>                
        <td><p>@b.CandidatInfo</p></td>
        <td><p>@b.CandidatPartion</p></td>
        <td><p>@b.CandidatProgramm</p></td>
        <td><p>@Html.ActionLink("Проголосовать", "Vote", "Home", new { id = @b.CandidatId, info= @b.CandidatInfo, data = @b.CandidatPartion }, null</p></td>
    </tr>
}
```

Вы должны именно по "id" отправлять потому что маршрутизация по умолчанию у вас такая

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

А далее вы эти "id, info, data" получаете в Controller - Home, в методе Vote

```
public ActionResult Vote(int? id, string info, string data)
{
    // Something
    return View()
}
```

Если я конечно правильно всё понял